# Type Inference and Generic Constructors of Generic and Non-Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics

I am reading the following,
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html
in particular the part "Type Inference and Generic Constructors of Generic and Non-Generic Classes".

I have tried to run the following:

```
public class MyClass < X > {

X myObject;

<T> MyClass(T t, X x) {
    myObject = x;
    System.out.println("t is " + x.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("x is " + t.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("myObject is " + myObject.getClass().getName());

    System.out.println("t value is " + t);
    System.out.println("x value is " + x);
    System.out.println("myObject value is " + myObject);

    myObject = new Integer(t); // 1 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "1";
    MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<>(myString, new Integer(myString));
}

}
```

but I get the following compilation error:

```
$javac -Xdiags:verbose MyClass.java 
MyClass.java:15: error: no suitable constructor found for Integer(T)
        myObject = new Integer(t); // 1 
                   ^
    constructor Integer.Integer(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to int)
    constructor Integer.Integer(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to String)
  where T,X are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in constructor <T>MyClass(T,X)
    X extends Object declared in class MyClass
1 error
```

If I comment //1 there is no error and the output is

```
t is java.lang.Integer
x is java.lang.String
myObject is java.lang.Integer
t value is 1
x value is 1
myObject value is 1
```

Can somebody tell me please what's happening and why the error?

Comment: parseInt takes a string. T is not necessarily a string. myObject holds an X, Integer is not necessarily an X

Comment: @Deadpool if X were Integer, it would be autoboxed

Comment: `MyClass<ServerSocket>(new Logger())`. Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the compiler's perspective:

`T` is not a `String`, which `Integer.parseInt(...)` expects to be passed in.

And `Integer.parseInt(...)` would return an `int` which is not an `X`.

Comment: T is not *necessarily* a string. It could be though. Same for X. It could be Integer, it just isn't definitely an Integer.

Comment: @Michael hairsplitting like that does not really get anyone anywhere. As far as the compiler is concerned `T` is not a `String`, the fact that it *may* be a `String` does not matter, it **is** not a `String`.